# Java - Swing - MVC/Observer Pattern - How to structure these 2 classes to obey MVC Pattern?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I am currently working on a bigger project for university in which I (we) create a small University Tycoon kind of game. I am currently working on the GUI stuff and I am kind of running into a problem with structuring my code.

I have 3 classes at this point that are a small extraction of the gui:

1. CreateGamePanel.java
2. TabbedPanePanel.java
3. UniversityView.java

Where UniversityView is part of the MVC pattern together with university.java and universityController.java. We have to use this obscure comination of MVC/Observer pattern. But let's start from the beginning:

CreateGamePanel is a JPanel that gives me the possiblity to create a new Game and input some data. It will then create the actuall University instance. The important part is this:

```
    }else if (e.getSource() == btnCreate){
        IConfig config = new Config(1);

        IUniversity university = new University(txtFldPlayerName.getText(),  txtFldUniversityName.getText(), config, getSelectedButtonDifficulty());
        UniversityView universityView = new UniversityView();
        UniversityController universityController = new UniversityController(university, universityView);

        TabbedPanePanel mainPanePanel = new TabbedPanePanel(universityView,universityController);

        frame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        frame.setContentPane(mainPanePanel);
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
```

Full Source here: http://pastebin.com/8rYBuyzN

As you can see it switches the panel from my frame to the next one. TabbedPanePanel. This will act as main Panel at this point. Everything GUI wise will come together at this TabbedPane.

Sourcecode for it is rather small: http://pastebin.com/MfDALzvF

Sourcecode for UniversityView: http://pastebin.com/VP3rYXq2

Now I want to create the Overview for the University. This should show me stuff like universityname, playername, year, etc. I have the methods to get this information from my model in my UniversityController. But the issue is that my UniversityView then needs to know the reference to UniversityController. But according to the MVC Pattern that shouldn't be the case.

Also according to our specification UniversityView acts as Observer for the University model.

All this confuses me a lot. So how can I unclutter this mess?

Comment: You may want to rephrase your title and contents slightly to remove the "best practice" vibe and focus more on "how do I couple these two classes together whilst obeying MVC". Otherwise the opinion-based closing squad will descend upon you and you'll get no answers :-(

Comment: Btw, those last two edits were minor in the extreme.

Comment: Edited the title. Hope it will fit better now. English is not my native language. Sorry about that!

Comment: Here's one example of a Java Swing application using MVC - [John Conway’s Game of Life](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=504).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what to specifically address, but to go over some things you have said:

> obscure comination of MVC/Observer pattern

The MVC pattern is often coded up using observers and events, especially when a lot of these actions can be asynchronous or when one action may take a long time (like querying over a network connection). It makes sense to do so in Swing to not hold up the EDT.

> But the issue is that my UniversityView then needs to know the reference to UniversityController

Doesn't sound like your view class needs to know a reference to controller. Your controller can know about view, and then when needed, give view an updated set of data for this university overview you describe.

There's no exact way to code up MVC. The purpose of patterns like these is for communication, and if you can code your program in some correct way, and it can be easily described to someone else using the term MVC, then you can say you've used MVC. There's only one specific method you should use to pass information between the model, view, and controller, and that's the one you've found to work well with your application.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you want to access information which is in view fields. To do this you dont need to have controller object in view. But you should have view and model both the objects in Controller. MVC pattern tells that all the connections between view and model should be done through controller only.

you can get some more information here  http://shulgadim.blogspot.in/2012/01/model-view-controller-mvc-pattern_13.html